# Oracle NUMBER(20) corresponding c# type?

Tags: c#, oracle, types

What is the corresponding C# type for an Oracle NUMBER(20)?  Oracle version is 8.

Update:

This is insert query. Then try adding the following parameter to command:

```
IDbDataParameter idParameter = cmd.CreateParameter();
idParameter.DbType = DbType.Int64;
idParameter.Value = id;
cmd.Parameters.Add(idParameter);
```

Oracle gives me exception: 
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [22007] [Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format

Comment: Which .NET ADO provider are you using?

Comment: You might want to check that error.  I don't think it has anything to do with the number, but that it's looking for a date.  ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format
Cause: The data to be converted to date format was incomplete; the date format picture was longer than the input data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error message `ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format` is not a datatype mapping error. This is the kind of error you get when Oracle fails a `TO_DATE` in some cases such as:

```
SQL> SELECT to_date('0101', 'ddmmyyyy') FROM dual;

ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format
```

I would look into your SQL query / PLSQL block for such an error.

Answer (score 1):

`decimal`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk72thhd.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a GetInt32() method to read the Data? Try Using GetDecimal() instead.

Comment: This is insert not select query.

Answer (score 0):

Int16 for values between -32768 and 32767, Int32 for values between -2147483648 and 2147483647, and Int64 for anything larger. refer [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleDbTypeEnumerationType.htm)